# Angular views, if not authenticated show single view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the SmartAdmin theme from wrapbootstrap.  I've added tons of my own Angular code ~5k loc.

So far I've used the theme's approach to view rendering, however, now it's become a problem and I need a way around it for the login page.

File Structure of project

```
project/
  assets/
    js/
      app/
        feature1/
          controller.js
          directive.js
          filter.js
  views/
    feature1/
      template.html
    feature2/
  index.html
```

When the user first goes to the project root, `index.html` is served up.  Inside `index.html` there are various `ng-includes` for the header, side nav, & footer.

I'm using JWT based authentication & authorization between each request, and if the user is not authenticated or time out it redirects to `/login` via `$location.path('/login');`

The problem with this is that it still shows the header, side nav, and footer (from `project/index.html`).  Is there anyway to get around this, and have it only use `index.html` if authenticated?

As you could expect I don't want the user to see header/sidenav/footer when not authenticated.  Regardless of the `templateUrl` I specify in the router the `index.html` is served and the `templateUrl` is used inside of it.  I need for this not to happen only on specific routes.

Edit:

The templates I use are inserted via the `<div ng-view></div>` in the `index.html`.

Mock up of `index.html` layout:

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="PageCtrl">
    <header ng-include="'templates/header.html'"></header>
    <aside ng-controller="'templates/left-panel.html'"></aside>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <footer ng-include="'templates/footer.html'"></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

And inside of `ng-view` each template has a controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution is to add and ng-hide to your nav and header that is dependent on the current route. 
I typically use the UI-router so I don't the services available offhand but add a comment if you can't figure it out and I'll take a look.

Comment: You're saying add `ng-hide` to my `ng-includes` and if the location is `login` set it equal to `true`?

Comment: Was able to figure it out from your tip.

Comment: Eh, actually this isn't good enough.  Is there anyway for me to have it reference a separate file?  When I add another `body` and attach a controller with `ng-show="true"` it shows the header, sidenav, and footer containers with no contents.

Comment: did you try adding it to the elements that have the ng-include directives?  <header ng-include="'templates/header.html'" ng-hide="loginstate"></header> for example.

Comment: That causes complications due to assets (css & js).  Ill just use server-side for the login unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-if is more secure and safe when playing with application security. ng-show and ng-hide will works but this only set/reset the visibility of the authenticated headers and menus.

So by setting a scope variable something like `$scope.authenticated = true;` at the time of authenticating in script part, and use that variable in template like `ng-if="authenticated"`.